# Generation of Service Reference and Web Reference is different

Tags: c#

I have a WSDL and I want to create client code for it. But I encounter a problem which I don't know why is it happened.

By adding as **service reference**:
It shows in my solution explorer but not in object browser, which I cannot call it.

By adding as **web reference**:
It shows both on solution explorer and object browser and I can call it.

Why is this happened? The WSDL is originally generated by Java and I want to use it for my C# project. For my previous WSDLs, they have no problem by adding as service reference.

Comment: Adding a **web reference** adds it as a *legacy* ASMX web service (web service technology up to .NET 2.0). Adding it as a **service reference** adds it using the WCF technology. This will **never** be the same! (since it's really two different things...)

Comment: @marc_s , but why my service reference cannot be found in Object browser? Is there any problem for the WSDL or any other thing?

Comment: Service Reference: Basically service reference is used in windows application with use of wcf service.
Web Reference: It is use in web application with use of web service as .asmx extension.